# Inner Join for list of records NOT in a second table (NOT Inner Join)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table let's call it products with a list of Manufacturers and Products.

I have a second table let's call it Customer, Orders.

I can do a join to make a list of all the items from each manufacturer the customer ordered doing an Inner Join. Yet trying to do an Inner Join for the items they did not fails.

I tried an Inner Join with 'Orders.Product != Products.Product' but that only works where the Customer has one order. Once there is more than one order I get the same list I would have doing an Inner Join. Any thoughts? I'll try to make a SqlFiddle tonight but was hoping a quick description might help a MySql / Join expert who has done 'NOT Inner Join'before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an anti join, you can use `left join` with `is null` check:

```
select p.* 
from products p 
left join orders o on p.Product = o.Product 
where o.product is null
```